# OpenID Login Helper Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid

Is there an easy way to implement OpenID login "helper buttons" similar to the buttons on the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=/) and [uservoice](http://uservoice.com/session/new) login pages if you're already using a library like DotNetOpenId?  It looks like [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/) solves half of the problem, but it would require re-implementing the login code to use their methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of open-source alternatives as well, which both depend on jQuery:

[openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) is an earlier version.

[openid-realselector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-realselector/) is a rewrite that is more jQuery-like and better-looking but less styleable.

Both are entirely JavaScript, so they're independent of your server-side choices.